# My :hover seem to be in conflict with something

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

Hello (baguette english here)
so i got a logo that should go down as you pass the cursor on it but it don't work at all and i don't know why here my code :

```css
.facebook{
  left: 0%;
  top:-10%;
  animation-name: logofb;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition-property: top;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes logofb  {
  from {top:-10%;}
  to {top: 0%;}
}

.facebook:hover {
  top: 50px;

}
```

```html
<span class="facebook reslogo"><img src=facebook.png height="13%" width="13%"></span>


.reslogo  {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 200;
  top: 0px;
}
```

The problem could come that it already have a animation that happen before

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this with keyframes instead of transform?

Comment: i don't know i just follow guide in internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a mix of units and positioning happening can be simplified. You can achieve this easily using `transform:translateY()`:

```css
.facebook {
  display:block;
  transform:translateY(-10%);
  transition:transform .5s ease;
}

.facebook:hover {
  transform:translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<span class="facebook"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png" height="13%" width="13%"></span>
```